# Volley request to Url with accent not Working

Tags: android, android-volley, postman

I am using Volley to perform requests to my api.

Using Postman if i execute a webservice to this url:

> ```
>    /api/Sample/Camión
> ```

It works there.

But when i execute the same WS using Volley (Android), it give me error, I am just sending the same url.

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: postman silently url-encodes your path parts. volley does not.

Comment: i think so. But,  how should i url-encode my path?, i try to use UrlEncode with utf-8 charset, but it doesnt work.

Comment: I fix it. I do it using Uri.encode(query).

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: yes, check my own answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that i must encode the string in the url before make the request.

Example

```
String searchUrl="camión";

Url=BaseUrl+Uri.encode(searchUrl)
```

For me that works, and the other thing is set utf-8 the the charset header.

Hope this help others.

Regards.